# HTML JavaScript not playing sound?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get sound to work for the following HTML-JavaScript code... but no sound and and the program doesn't say "No sound support".  Not sure what the problem is ??

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sound Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PlaySound(){
    var sound = document.getElementById("note_c1");
    try{
        //RealPlayer
        sound.DoPlay();
    }catch (e){
        try{
            //Windows Media / Quicktime
            sound.Play();
            alert("should hear sound");
        }catch(e){
            alert("No sound support.");
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sound Test</h1>
<embed id="note_c1" src="c1.au" width="0" height="0" autostart="false" enablejavascript="true"/>
<input type = "button" value="Play the Sound" onClick="PlaySound()">
</body>
```

Comment: May i know which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.jplayer.org/.

I have no affiliation - It's simple, highly configurable, will work on a larger set of clients and far more future proof (and no forking code).

Happy Coding :)